# LVM corruption, perhaps, or other hard drive boot error?

Tags: restore, boot, lvm, fedora-23

Had been using Fedora Core 23 for a few months and then turned on the computer, entered my boot password, and instead of getting the user login screen as usual I got the following message after it had booted:

```
Generating "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt"
Entering emergency mode
Exit the shell to continue
Type "journalctl" to view system logs.
:/#
```

I tried looking at the report and there were a number of lines in red, errors such as:

```
"Buffer error I/O dw dm-1"

"error {UNC}"

"Read FPDMA Queued"

"fsck failed error 4"

"res (long MAC address looking numbers, then) media error F"

"Blk update request I/O error dev/sda"

Towards the end of the file:

"Dependency failed for /sysroot"

"Dependency failed for INITRD root file system"
```

Not in exact order.

I tried running "fsck" ("/sbin/fsck") but it didn't do anything.

Anyone out there know if I'm just totally hosed and need to reinstall from scratch and hope I have backups?  Or is there any way to fix the LVM config or whatever else might be causing this?  S.O.S.

Thank you for any and all help...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to boot into rescue mode and repair the disks.